# How can a user-defined function not be returning accurate data?

Tags: excel, vba

My formula is similar to a vlookup but it allows for filtering based on 1 extra piece of criteria that creates additional filtering.

Simple break down of the code:

1. Find all key value pairs in key-value pairs worksheet
2. Filter key value pairs down to 1 value based on what is needed for that specific column
3. Return value from keywords worksheet

All this to say, my issue doesn't seem to involve my code but appears to be more on excel's side but I included my VBA anyway just to be safe. So here is my question, has anyone experienced where your formulas don't update properly in excel? I added my formula to excel using:

`=@VBAProject.getTag.getTag($A43,AP$2:AP$4,"keywords",2)`

and it says there is a key-value pair when I initially input the formula. This isn't true. I then make that cell recalculate my formula and the value disappears like it should. I hope this makes sense, please let me know if you need additional clarity.

**SAMPLE**

*Primary worksheet with formula*

[image: primary worksheet]

*Key-value pairs ("contact_keywords")*

[image: key-value]

*Values ("keywords")*

[image: return values]

**ERROR EXAMPLE**

*Formula returns wrong keyword*

[image: Error exmample]

*I then make the formula recalculate and the error clears for contactid 3*

[image: error cleared]

Here is where my question intially started:[How do I get rid of a "Compile Error: Invalid qualifier" on the first line of vba code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908110/how-do-i-get-rid-of-a-compile-error-invalid-qualifier-on-the-first-line-of-vb#63908110)

As stated in the previous question, I know my code is janky. I just need to get this done.

```
Public Static Function getTag(contactId As Range, localKeywords As Range, kwsName As String, returnColumn As Integer) As String

    Dim matchedKeywords(1 To 10) As String
    Dim counter As Integer, matchedCounter As Integer
    Dim finalKeyword As String
    Dim ckws As Worksheet
    Dim kws As Worksheet
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim ckR As Range
    Dim kR As Range

    Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    If StrComp(kwsName, "keywords") = 0 Then
        Set ckws = wkb.Sheets("contact_keywords")
        Set ckR = ckws.Range("B2:B1510")
        Set kws = wkb.Sheets(kwsName)
        Set kR = kws.Range("A2:A55")
    Else
        Set ckws = wkb.Sheets("contact_tags_members")
        Set ckR = ckws.Range("B2:B2380")
        Set kws = wkb.Sheets(kwsName)
        Set kR = kws.Range("A2:A41")
    End If
    
    counter = 1
    matchedCounter = 1
    
    For Each pairingId In ckR
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'This gets all the keywords related to the client
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    
        If (StrComp(pairingId, contactId.Value) = 0) Then
           
            matchedKeywords(matchedCounter) = ckws.Range("C" & pairingId.Row).Value
            matchedCounter = matchedCounter + 1
            
        End If
        
        counter = counter + 1
        
    Next
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Check if first index is filled in
    '''''''''''''''''''''''
    
    If matchedKeywords(1) <> "" Then
    
        For Each matchedKeyword In matchedKeywords
        ''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Sort through keywords to make sure they match the list above
        ' Narrow down to 1 keyword
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            For Each localKeyword In localKeywords
                If (StrComp(matchedKeyword, localKeyword) = 0) Then
                    finalKeyword = localKeyword
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            
            If finalKeyword <> "" Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        
        For Each returnKeyword In kR
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Find & return the needed value
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            If (StrComp(returnKeyword, finalKeyword) = 0) Then
                getTag = kR.Cells(returnKeyword.Row, returnColumn).Value
                Exit Function
            End If
        
        Next
    
    End If
    
    getTag = ""
    
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried placing Application.Volatile at the beginning of the code in your function?

Comment: @RetiredGeek I added `Application.Volatile` per your recommendation and it didn't seem to make any difference. Any other thoughts?